# printing data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to count the fruit that have a days value of greater than or equal to 3

```
#get fruit that have been in the basket for 3 plus days
fruit_over_3_days = df[df.days >= 3]

#get count of the fruit
count_of_fruit_3_days = fruit_over_3_days['fruit'].value_counts()
```

```
results in dataframe
watermelon    2
pineapple     2
orange        2
apple         1
grapefruit    1
```

I have all the right results but I can't figure out how to get the data out of the dataframe.  I want to print the results to be 2 watermelon, 2 pineapple, 2 orangea, 1 apple and 1 grapefruit are over 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the result

```
','.join(count_of_fruit_3_days.astype(str) +' '+ count_of_fruit_3_days.index)
'2 watermelon,2 pineapple,2 orange,1 apple,1 grapefruit'
```